# Monad instance of a number-parameterised vector?

Tags: haskell, types, monads

Statically sized vectors in Haskell are shown in Oleg Kiselyov's [Number-parameterized types](http://okmij.org/ftp/papers/number-parameterized-types.pdf) and can also be found in the `Data.Param.FSVec` type from the [parameterized-data](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parameterized-data-0.1.5) module on Hackage:

```
data Nat s => FSVec s a
```

`FSVec` is not an instance of the `Monad` type class.

The monad instance for lists, can be used to remove or duplicate elements:

```
Prelude> [1,2,3] >>= \i -> case i of 1 -> [1,1]; 2 -> []; _ -> [i]
[1,1,3]
```

Whether similar to the list version or not, is it possible to construct a monad from a fixed length vector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible, if not natural.

The monad has to 'diagonalize' the result in order to satisfy the monad laws.

That is to say, you can look at a vector as a tabulated function from `[0..n-1] -> a` and then adapt the monad instance for functions.

The resulting `join` operation takes a square matrix in the form of a vector of vectors and returns its diagonal.

Given

```
tabulate :: Pos n => (forall m. (Nat m, m :<: n) => m -> a) -> FSVec n a
```

then

```
instance Pos n => Monad (FSVec n) where
     return = copy (toNum undefined)
     v >>= f = tabulate (\i -> f (v ! i) ! i)
```

Sadly *uses* of this monad are somewhat limited.

I have a half-dozen variations on the theme in my [streams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streams) package and Jeremy Gibbons wrote a [blog post](http://patternsinfp.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/stream-monad/) on this monad.

Equivalently, you can view a `FSVec n` as a [representable functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representable_functor) with its representation being natural numbers bounded by n, then use the definitions of `bindRep` and `pureRep` in my [representable-functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/representable-functors/0.3.0.3/doc/html/Data-Functor-Representable.html) package to get the definition automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Alternatively, I imagine taking the nth element of each vector would break a monad law. I'll look for Jeremy's article.

Comment: Correct. The second monad law would break because m >>= return would not equal m

Comment: I think [this](http://patternsinfp.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/stream-monad/) is it. Jeremy uses the same diagonal idea on the stream monad. I had actually read and forgotten the article. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah yes, I always forget about the diagonalizing monad. It's too weird. :)

Comment: Added the link to Jeremy's post to my reply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Edward. I don't (yet) know how to use tabulate and index. I guess their use gives many of the benefits typically associated with your packages. Can I ask, are they though any easier to define than return and bind? p.s. Is that the copy function from Bananas in Space?

Comment: The idea of a representable functor (when translated into Haskell) is that the functor `f` is isomorphic to a function from some type `x`. We usually call that type `x` along with the isomorphism the representation of `f`. `representable-functors` witnesses this isomorphism with two functions: `tabulate :: (x -> a) -> f a` and `index :: f a -> (x -> a)`. Any example is the Functor given by `data Pair a = Pair a a` which is representable by `Bool`. In this case `tabulate f = Pair (f False) (f True);` and  `index (Pair _ f) False = f; index (Pair t _) True = t`.

Comment: Given tabulate and index as inverses you can say an awful lot about `f`. Since it is isomorphic to `(->) x`, you can borrow the instances for `(->) x`. Since `(->) x` is a right adjoint, it preserves limits, which means it is an instance of `Distributive`, but `(->) x` is also a `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad`, etc. This is why there are so many different `fooRep` methods that provide default definitions for various methods from other classes for any `Representable`.

Comment: `copy` is just the copy from oleg's `parameterized-data`, which provides a natural number indexed replicate function. The type of the argument to toNat there is constrained by the result type of return.

Comment: `tabulate` and `index` together are more powerful (when available) than `return` and `(>>=)`. As you can see from Gibbons' article the definition of the monad for fixed length or always-infinite vectors is a bit hairy, and if you look at the asymptotic performance of the two it is the same. But had Oleg chosen to use a fixed length array rather than a `[a]` behind the scenes, the tabulate version of (>>=) could be faster. An example of how to define something similar to this iteratively is in http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/streams/0.6.1.1/doc/html/src/Data-Stream-Infinite.html

Answer (score 2):

That seems impossible given that any monad has a join function. If the vector size is not exactly zero or one this would change the vector size.  You can make it a Functor and Applicative, though.

Comment: It is possible if somewhat strange. See my response. Jeremy Gibbons wrote a nice article on this monad at some point.

Answer (score -3):

Sure you can do that. Just write

```
instance Monad (FSVec s) where
      -- your definition of return
      -- your definition of >>=
```