# Representable Functor isomorphic to (Bool -> a)

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory

I thought I'd try the intriguing [Representable-functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/representable-functors/0.3.0.3/doc/html/Data-Functor-Representable.html) package to define a `Monad` and `Comonad` instance for the functor given by `data Pair a = Pair a a` which is representable by `Bool`; as mentioned in the answer to [my earlier question on the vector monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802628/monad-instance-of-a-number-parameterised-vector).

The first thing I noticed was that to make my type an instance of `Representable`, I should not only define `tabulate` and `index`, but also ensure my type is an instance of the `Indexable`, `Distributive`, `Keyed`, `Apply`, `Applicative`, and `Functor` type classes. Well, ok, `index` completes the definition of `Indexable`, and the `<.>` function of `Apply` can use `<*>` from `Applicative`; and it shouldn't be a surprise that a `Functor` instance is required. Nevertheless, I am doubtful of my instances for `Keyed` and `Distributive`.

```
data Pair a = Pair a a
  deriving (Show,Eq)

instance Functor Pair where
  fmap f (Pair x y) = Pair (f x) (f y)

type instance Key Pair = Bool

instance Keyed Pair where
  mapWithKey f (Pair x y) = Pair (f False x) (f False y)

instance Indexable Pair where
  index (Pair x _) False = x
  index (Pair _ y) True  = y

instance Applicative Pair where
  pure a = Pair a a
  Pair f g <*> Pair x y = Pair (f x) (g y)

instance Apply Pair where
  (<.>) = (<*>)

instance Distributive Pair where
  collect f x = Pair (getL . f <$> x) (getR . f <$> x)
    where getL (Pair x _) = x
          getR (Pair _ y) = y

instance Representable Pair where
  tabulate f = Pair (f False) (f True)
```

My `mapWithKey` definition borrows from that of the `[]` instance for `Keyed`: though I don't understand why `0` was used there for every iteration. I have similarly used `False` for each term of `Pair`.

As I concluded by defining the `Monad` and `Comonad` instances, I discovered that `Bool` requires a `Semigroup` definition for `Extend`, and a `Monoid` definition for `Comonad`. I follow the `Semigroup` instance for the `Either`, which is isomorphic to `(||)`, and choose `False` for `mempty`:

```
instance Monad Pair where
  return = pureRep
  (>>=)  = bindRep

instance Monoid Bool where
  mempty = False
  mappend = (||)

instance Semigroup Bool where
  (<>) = mappend

instance Extend Pair where
  extend = extendRep -- needs Bool Semigroup

instance Comonad Pair where
  extract = extractRep -- needs Bool Monoid
```

So then, have I met the requirements of the `Representable` class correctly, and idiomatically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you have. Though your instance for `Keyed` is off.

```
instance Keyed Pair where
    mapWithKey f (Pair x y) = Pair (f False x) (f True y)
```

or even easier

```
instance Keyed Pair where
    mapWithKey = mapWithKeyRep
```

and similarly

```
instance Distributive Pair where
    distribute = distributeRep
```

Given `index` and `tabulate` you can use the various `fooRep` methods in the `Representable` module to provide definitions for all of the other superclasses.

The `Extend` and `Comonad` definitions, are not actually part of the requirements to be `Representable`. They are included though, because being representable means you are isomorphic to a function, which enables you to recycle the definition for the "exponential" `Comonad` (aka cowriter, or [Traced](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonad-transformers/1.6.3/doc/html/Control-Comonad-Trans-Traced.html) comonad) to become a `Comonad` as well, given some monoid on your representation. This isn't required though, mainly because I can't constrain it to hold given the types involved.

You may want to drop the `Semigroup` and `Monoid` for `Bool` though and just hand implement `extend` and `extract`. It is easy enough.

```
instance Extend Pair where
    extend f p@(Pair a b) = Pair (f p) (f (Pair b a))

instance Comonad Pair where
    extract (Pair a b) = a
```

Also, this type is [provided](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/representable-tries/0.3.6/doc/html/Data-Functor-Representable-Trie-Bool.html) by the [representable-tries](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/representable-tries-0.3.6) package, which includes a number of other instances.

And,

```
import Control.Applicative
bool = [True, False]
f tt _tf _ft _ff True  True  = tt
f _tt tf _ft _ff True  False = tf
f _tt _tf ft _ff False True  = ft
f _tt _tf _ft ff False False = ff
associative f = and (assoc <$> bool <*> bool <*> bool) where 
    assoc a b c = f (f a b) c == f a (f b c)
semigroups = filter associative 
    [ f tt tf ft ff | tt <- bool, tf <- bool, ft <- bool, ff <- bool ]
unital (u, f) = all unit bool where 
    unit a = f u a == a && f a u == a
monoids = filter unital 
    [ (u, f) | u <- bool, f <- semigroups ]
```

shows that as you surmised there are the 4 possible monoids you surmised and if you only want an extend instance, there are 8 semigroups available.

Comment: I'm glad to see that I had `Keyed` wrong. I'm still a little confused by the `[]` instance (for `Keyed`) though. It uses `0` for every iteration?

Comment: If it does then it is a bug. it should be counting up from 0 as it goes. I'll fix it.

Comment: Fixed. keys-0.2.7 has the fixed list instances. I'll upload upgraded versions of its downstream dependents later on. In the meantime you can uninstall keys-0.2.6 and whatever depends on it, and reinstall.

Comment: Nice. I'd assumed that I couldn't use, say `mapWithKeyRep`, until I'd "fully" defined the `Representable` instance; which after all needs a `Keyed` instance. I should know better from Haskell by now... I will look at the representable-tries. I wonder if your `Trie`s are equivalent to the classic Trie, aka. prefix tree. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed `duplicate (Pair 1 2)` gives a different result if I use your extract definition. It seems that it's my definition of `mappend` accounts for this. If I use XOR instead of OR, I get the same result as you. Is this a choice that impedes on a Comonad law?

Comment: Both are valid. You only need associativity and a unit on the argument. The choice is arbitrary. If none makes sense then you are perfectly within your rights to leave off the comonad entirely.

Comment: As for the representable-tries package, it provides "memo-tries". This means they are fully populated tries with lazily populated leaves, rather than a prefix trie which only has inhabitants for some keys.

Comment: XOR (/=) is a monoid, with False as identity (isomorphic to Z_2).

Comment: As you noticed above, I meant your `extend` definition; not `extract`. Anyway...I was thinking, as there is also (True,AND) and (True,XNOR). Does that mean there are exactly/only 4 possible Comonad instances for `Pair`; aka. `(Bool->a)`?

Comment: Yep. I added the derivation of that fact in the answer above.

Comment: Are semigroups 6 and 8 OK? `let f = (semigroups !! 6) in [f (f a b) c == f a (f b c) | [a,b,c] <- sequence $ replicate 3 [False,True]]` gives `[True,False,True,False,False,True,False,True]` I'm not sure though.

Comment: Fixed. I'd used zipWith3 instead of liftA3. There are 8 semigroups, not 10. ;) I'd only been checking the True True True and False False False cases. ;)

Comment: Ah yes, good ol' liftA3! Ok then, enough's enough: in conclusion, I had no choice in the monad, but 4 possible comonads; so monads are in some sense "rarer" than comonads? Also, is the above monad of the `Pair` representable functor, by any chance also its free monad?

Comment: Nah they aren't any rarer or more common. Consider the other side of the adjunction. If you look at (,) Bool, as a Comonad you only have one viable definition: extract = snd; duplicate ea@(e,_) = (e,ea); but there are 4 monads, depending on which Monoid you pick, mirroring the scenario here.